# Define new void event

Tags: c#, events, void

is there any way to attach an event handler without creating a new method?  I suspect it would look something like this:

```
 TextBox1.TextChanged += new void(object s, EventArgs arg)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(arg.HashCode.ToString())
 };
```

Answer (score 9):

```
TextBox1.TextChanged+= (s,arg)=>{MessageBox.Show(arg.HashCode.ToString())};
```

Comment: Doesn't this essentially do the same thing?

Comment: Gotta love syntactic sugar!

Comment: Isn't "the same thing" what he asked for?

Comment: Well, probably. Not sure if the OP truly literally meant *without creating a new anonymous void method* or not.

Comment: My post has been edited, this is what i was looking for, ty very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous method, as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the MSDN:

```
// Create a handler for a click event
button1.Click += delegate(System.Object o, System.EventArgs e)
                   { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Click!"); };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method, which I would argue is more readable in this case:

```
TextBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged;

private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object s, EventArgs arg)
{
    MessageBox.Show(arg.GetHashCode().ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a non-anonymous method instead:

```
void TextBox1_TextChanged(object s, EventArgs arg)
{
    MessageBox.Show(arg.HashCode.ToString());
}

void HandleEvent()
{
    TextBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: but they're so much less fun, and in any case, it's not the question; the question is if it's possible and how to create an anonymous method.

Comment: @Servy The question as I read it is "how to do the event without creating a new void". This will definitely "do the event" and will not "create a new void".

Comment: It's pretty clear that by "create a new void" he means "create a new method", since you can't ever create a "void" (by definition, since void means "nothingness" and so can never exist, ever).

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful:

```
this.TextBox1.TextChanged += (sender, eventargs) => Console.WriteLine("Do something here !!");
```